# How to find the URL to a specific contact in Office365

Tags: office365

I am working on an application which lists a number of people from your Office365 Outlook Contacts. I can get the contacts with the Exchange Web Services. From there I know the contact item ID. But is there any way to create a clickable link that, if there is an open browser session with Office 365, shows that specific contact within the browser?

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I found this example for e-mail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.webclientreadformquerystring(v=exchg.80).aspx

Example url for a contact, by using contact.WebClientReadFormQueryString:

"https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADYxMmVkZjVkLTVjMmQtNDgxMC1iMDY1LWVkY2U2ZGMzNDcwOABGAAAAAABG6y7fCOAuSoTyelb8%2BBhzBwBkKbdzLh23R5sshtN5ElpGAAAAAAEPAABkKbdzLh23R5sshtN5ElpGAAAasnQqAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=PersonaCardViewModelFactory"

Unfortunally, calling this URL results in OWA remaining in a loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. The property is called WebClientReadFormQueryString. You will use the value of that property build the URL to make a link to the client from OWA. I think the base URL is "https://outlook.office365.com"

Comment: Micheal, thanks for your answer! However, I am still not getting this to work. Like Erriez, when I try the example code for office365 my OWA remains in the loading screen. Do you know what form the URL should have?

Comment: Better yet, have you seen this function work with Office365? According to this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2888274 this function had a bug which was supposedly fixed. But maybe not for Office365?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on calendars with CalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory, after much debugging I was at a loss but saw someone express how to manually generate a link for calendars on older version.  Then I realized MS was not returning the viewmodel as an interface they expected (ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory).  Appending I in front of the name worked on calendar, however PersonaCardViewModelFactory seems to still be at a loss even when changing it to IPersonaCardViewModelFactory.  Only choice left is to call MS.

Comment: Removing the viewmodel from persona gets it to open for now.  We have a ticket open with MS for this issue.  Also redirect unencodes the itemid, other problem we had.

Comment: Are there any updates? Still can't make it work. I'm getting data through Microsoft Graph

Comment: Left the company before getting a response unfortunately.