# How to open specific email item in OWA from URL

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

I am currently building a web application using the office 365 APIs to display emails, files, and calendar items that are being grabbed from Office365. I am looking to open up the OWA into the specific email, or calendar event. I've been searching for documentation on parameters that can be passed into OWA but I haven't been able to find much.

I've been able to find examples such as this outlook.com/owa/OURURL/#viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory&wid=91&ispopout=1 which open up a new email composition, but not much else. If you check the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.webclientreadformquerystring(v=exchg.80).aspx it looks like there is a paramater #viewmodel=_y.$Ep&ItemID=, but this is only supposed to be used for exchange 2013.

If anyone has any information on documentation regarding this functionality or any other help, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: You should also be able to use webclientreadformquerystring to create URLs to contacts, but I can't get it to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947392/how-to-find-the-url-to-a-specific-contact-in-office365/25189626#25189626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your post and for using Office 365 REST APIs!  We don't yet provide a URL property on a message, event or a contact to open it in Outlook Web App (OWA).  As we have received multiple requests for this feature, this is on our roadmap.  So, please stay tuned ...

[UPDATE] You can now get the OWA URL using a property called WebLink for Message and Event.  For example:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Messages?$select=WebLink

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Events?$select=WebLink

Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was also wondering if you could get URLs for specific OneDrive documents within the OWA as well? I can see a familiarity between some of the URLs so I could jerry-rig it, but I am not sure if it might change in the future. Any advice?

Comment: Are there any changes? I want to do it for personal contact and I'm using Microsoft Graph for access.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand how to use these at all. I get a request for user and pass. I'm using OWA in two contexts: corporation using outlook web within their domain, and corporation asking us to log into MS's main outlook (using our domain name).